# How to make a zigzag border with a shadow in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, borders

I would like to know how to achieve this zigzag effect (including the shadow) in Photoshop CS6:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a triangle brush by drawing a triangle with the Polygon select tool, fill it with black, and click *Edit > Define brush preset*. Adjust the spacing in the Brush Settings panel so that you have slightly overlapping triangles.
2. Choose a grey colour as the foreground colour. Fill the entire background layer with that grey.
3. Add a new layer, then with the Rectangle Select tool, make a selection of the entire page except for a small border along the bottom, and fill it with the same grey. Then do *Select > Deselect*.
4. Hide the background layer so you can see what you are doing next.
5. Use the Brush Tool along the bottom, click once at one edge, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click once beyond the bounds of the opposite edge. This will draw triangles between the first and last click.
6. Apply a drop shadow layer effect, adjust the shadow as required.
7. Unhide the background layer.

For example:

[image]

8. To get the shadow to fade at the left and right edges, right click the layer in the layers panel and choose the option to rasterize the layer styles.
9. In the Layers panel, engage the pixel lock
10. With a large fuzzy round edged brush, with the opacity turned down low, paint over the edges so the shadow fades out.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick and easy method in Photoshop. THe pen tool and drawing it manually is probably the easiest way.

If you have access to a vector app such as Illustrator, you could simply draw a path then use Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag and then copy the result to Photoshop.

Comment: Add it as a smart object from Illustrator and then you can always jump back and edit it there if something changes. Personally, I'd just save myself the hassle and build the whole thing in Illy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a sans-serif font
2. Type a few letter "V"s
3. On the character palette make the horizontal scale larger and the kerning smaller until it gets a nice wide "V" that touches
4. Layer Style > Drop Shadow

For step 4 depending on the exact effect you want you're going to need to do some other things probably like rasterize the layer and append a rectangle on to the top of it so when you do the drop shadow it only shows on the bottom. You might also then want to add a layer under it and fine touch it a little with the airbrush because as you see the shadow is a bit darker in the middle then on the edges. A very large soft airbrush right in the middle on a layer underneath should get that effect added in for you.

Hope this helps.